# Run Ratchet on a subdomain as a complete own service to provide a custom WebSocket

Tags: php, websocket, subdomain, ratchet

I'm currently trying to host my own WebSocket server using Ratchet http://socketo.me/docs/push.

The problem is that I can't find a good tutorial that shows me how I can host this on a subdomain. So hopefully someone can help me here.

**My plan:**

I already have a basic auth secured subdomain called `ws.my-domain.de`. Now I want to run Ratchet on my subdomain to provide this as a service for my main domain and all my subdomains.

At my main domain `my-domain.de` I've WordPress running so this is where I want to use my own WebSocket first via the client side tutorial from the page I've posted above:

```
<script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cboden/fcae978cfc016d506639c5241f94e772/raw/e974ce895df527c83b8e010124a034cfcf6c9f4b/autobahn.js"></script>
<script>
    var conn = new ab.Session('ws://ws.my-domain.de',
        function() {
            conn.subscribe('kittensCategory', function(topic, data) {
                // This is where you would add the new article to the DOM (beyond the scope of this tutorial)
                console.log('New article published to category "' + topic + '" : ' + data.title);
            });
        },
        function() {
            console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
        },
        {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
    );
</script>
```

So can please someone show me the steps I need to do? I'm completely new with this. I know how to use it on the client side, but I don't know how to provide it as a service and then use it in PHP (WordPress).

Comment: Status: I've already created my subdomain and setup a repository. I've tried some things out but I can't still get it to work. I'm not sure which part needs to be on my subdomain and which one in my project to use it.

Comment: Does anyone has an idea how I can go for this?

Comment: I'll delete my question tomorrow if no one knows an answer because in this case I will keep my current solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are on a VPS or dedicated server.

You need to run your WebSocket as a daemon and then create a vhost for your subdomain in Nginx or Apache and using that create a reverse proxy to your WebSocket server.

[Running ratchet as a daemon](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/783#issuecomment-588528879)

[Nginx WebSocket reverse proxy](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/)

[Apache WebSocket reverse proxy](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/how-to-reverse-proxy-websockets-with-apache-2-4/)